# Fun: Can you construct infinitely many non-homeomorphic connected subsets of the plane.

Tags: general-topology, recreational-mathematics

Can you construct infinitely many non-homeomorphic connected subsets of the
plane.

I think this is possible, would:

$I_N = \bigcup_{n=1}^{N} I_n$ for $N \in \mathbb{N}$

where

$$I_n = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : (x-\frac{1}{n})^2+y^2= \frac{1}{n}\}$$

work?

Comment: I imagine this is true- In my mind I am considering subsets which are connected but but not path connected- like the topologists sine curve- and having different numbers of path connected components.  So for example, where the topologists sine curve isn't path connected at the $y$-axis, we could repeat this along the $x$-axis as many times as we wanted. And as path connectedness is a topological invariant these can't be homeomorphic? Maybe your example works too, I haven't thought about it much to be honest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is almost fine, except it should be $\frac{1}{n^2}$ (square of the radius of the circle) and you should also prove that the sets $I_N$ are pairwise nonhomeomorphic (this is not hard). More interestingly, there are
$$2^{2^{\aleph_0}}= 2^{{\mathfrak c}}$$ of pairwise nonhomeomorphic subsets of the real line.  This is not easy, if you are interested, I can explain why.

Edit. Let me prove that there are $2^{{\mathfrak c}}$ of pairwise nonhomeomorphic subsets of the real line. First of all, clearly, there are $2^{{\mathfrak c}}$ subsets of the real line. Now, there is an interesting  theorem of M.A.Lavrentiev (mostly famous for his contributions to applied mathematics):

**Theorem.** For any pair of completely metrizable spaces $X, Y$ (I will be using $X=Y={\mathbb R}$), for any two subsets $A\subset X, B\subset Y$ and any homeomorphism $h: A\to B$, there exist $G_\delta$-subsets $A', B'\subset {\mathbb R}$ such that $A\subset A', B\subset B'$ and $h$ extends to a homeomorphism
$$
h': A'\to B'.
$$
For a proof see for instance Theorem 4.3.21 in, R. Engelking, "General topology", Heldermann Verlag, Berlin, 1989.

Since there are exactly ${\mathfrak c}$ distinct [$G_\delta$-subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set) of ${\mathbb R}$ (every such subset is determined by a countable sequence of real numbers) and there is  at most continuum of homeomorphisms between such subsets, it follows 
that each subset $A\subset {\mathbb R}$ is homeomorphic to at most 
${\mathfrak c}$ distinct subsets of ${\mathbb R}$. Hence, it follows that ${\mathbb R}$ contains exactly  $2^{{\mathfrak c}}$ pairwise nonhomeomorphic subsets.

Comment: Thanks for the great responses everyone. I chose this answer as I am interested in knowing why Cohen's example is true.

Answer (score 1):

One way: there is, for every countable ordinal $\alpha < \omega_!$ an embedding $i_\alpha: \alpha \to \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ and we can take the cone over $i_\alpha[\alpha]$ as one of the (path-)connected sets.

Answer (score 1):

Another way: you can just connect the origin to $n$ distinct points on a circle around the it by a line segment.

As a side note, much stronger results are true: there are continuum-many pairwise non-homeomorphic planar continua (compact connected subsets of a plane), actually closures of piecewise linear graphs $[0, 1) → [0, 1]$ can be taken.